# Redirect Http and www subdomain traffic to https automatically

Tags: .htaccess

I used the following code on my `.htaccess` to redirect `http` and `www` traffic to `https`. I am using this htaccess config with my `Laravel` project.

The problem i am facing is that when i work locally it redirects me to `https` on `.local` domain. It creates issues as i can not configure https locally.

So what is the recommended way to redirect `http` and `www` to `https` on multiple environments like local, production.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Redirect everything to https
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Any reason why you can't disable the https redirect on local?

Comment: @Mozammil actually i do not know how to disable the https redirect or enable https for the .local domains. this is the question i asked here

Answer (score 1):

RewriteCond is your "if-condition". Just add after

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !127.0.0.1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

In `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` you can force all route or asset links to https:

```php
if (config('app.env') === 'production') {
    URL::forceScheme('https');
}
```

Then create a middleware to force all requests to secure requests:

```php
php artisan make:middleware SecureSite
```

Open `SecureSite.php` in `app/Http/Middleware` folder and overwrite the `handle()` function:

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (config('app.env') === 'production' && !$request->isSecure()) {
        return redirect()->secure($request->getRequestUri());
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Then in `app/Http/Kernel.php` add it first in your `$middlewareGroups` under `web`:

```php
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\SecureSite::class,
        ...
```

Then make sure all your `web.php` routes have `web` middleware:

```php
php artisan route:list
```

No need to change `.htaccess`, [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/laravel/laravel/master/public/.htaccess) is the original `.htaccess` if you want to revert.

Answer (score 0):

Updated the `.htaccess` as following and it is working now. Thanks for your help.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Redirect everything to https
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !127.0.0.1
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !localhost
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !\.local$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
</IfModule>
```